# Is it safe to remove runit package?

Tags: apt, lts, runit

I just upgraded my ubuntu box from 12.04 LST to 14.04 LTS.
Now apt-get tells me:

> The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
>      runit
>    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.

Is it really safe to remove this package? `dpkg-query -L runit` shows me a list of iles that look pretty important to me...

Thanks for the advice,
Massimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runit` is an alternative process supervisor (a la Upstart, Systemd, supervisord, watchdog, etc, etc, etc). It's not a default-install package.

I suspect you had it installed because you have recently removed something that depends on it. The current 12.04 list is below:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends runit
runit
Reverse Depends:
  dropbear
  dropbear
  vblade-persist
  twoftpd-run
  twoftpd
 |tinydyndns
  socklog-run
  socklog
  roundup
 |qmail-run
  mailfront
  ipsvd
  git-daemon-run
  dropbear
  dnscache-run
  djbdns
  dbndns
  daemontools-run
  daemontools
  cereal
  bcron-run
  bcron
```

Comment: Yes, I did removed git-daemon-run because I got the following error:
git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.